# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

Hi i'm sending a integer array to my spring mvc controller method.When it is passed the data is getting to controller and functionality is working good.
But after the function the controller will send some response to client side, on client side the response data goes to error function and showing

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d



$.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                dataType : 'json',
                url : 'deleteTeacherSelectedNotes.html',
                data : ({
                    notes : JSON.stringify(noteArray)
                }),
                success : function(responseData) {
                    stopPreloader();
                                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                        console.log("Message: " + r.Message);
                        console.log("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                        console.log("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
                  }
                });





    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteTeacherSelectedNotes.html", method =  RequestMethod.GET)
            @ResponseBody
            public boolean deleteTeacherSelectedNotes(@RequestParam("notes")String notes) throws JSONException{
                JSONArray arrJson = new JSONArray(notes);
                for (int i = 0; i < arrJson.length(); i++) {
                    String x = arrJson.getString(i);
                    noteService.deleteNote(Integer.parseInt(x));
                }
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Changing data type to JSON

```
$.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                dataType : 'JSON',
                url : 'deleteTeacherSelectedNotes.html',
                data : ({
                    notes : JSON.stringify(noteArray)
                }),
                success : function(responseData) {
                    stopPreloader();
                                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                        console.log("Message: " + r.Message);
                        console.log("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                        console.log("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
                  }
                });
```

Comment: thanks working good...
so whats the difference between json and JSON ??

Comment: JSON is the datatype (keyword) For exapme int,float if you will write INT then that will not work.